# Wifi - No Adaptors listed in WPA-GUI - Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I have an ALFA AWUS036NH WiFi device with the RT3070 chipset and there is no adapter listed in the WPA-GUI. lsusb does show the device.

If I use a different WiFi device with the RT5370 chipset, wlan0 is listed in the WPA-GUI and I can connect to my wireless network.

Why does the RT3070 not show up in the WPA-GUI?

Comment: Do you have the proper drivers installed?

Comment: Could you show the result of `lsusb -v`?

Comment: How can I determine if the proper drivers are installed?